# why does it take long to get massive rest api response?

Tags: spring, rest, http, ftp

I got the API returning string response over 5MB.

As I call the API on chrome and see Network tap of Developer Tool.

Waiting (TTFB) : 189.65 ms

Content Download : 4.97 s

Why does it take too long for content download comparing to downloading 5MB single file via ftp?

P.S : It takes 1 sec to download 5MB single file via ftp from the same server which API server(Spring) is running.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is limited by not only the network speed (which is obviously not the reason if you can download the same quantity faster by another way), but also the server's ability to provide the data. The developer tools just told you that it took the server (189.65ms - travel time) to generate the first byte, and (189.65ms + 4.97s - travel time) to generate the last byte; but you can't know what it was doing in the meantime. For all you know, the code could have included `sleep(4)`; you can't know why it took as much time unless you profile the serverside process that provided the data.